SharePoint Library intake form - Error with Powerapps, but not default form?
I have a SharePoint library where I need to user PowerApps for the intake form (to create a new document set).
I keep getting an error:

Network error when using patch function. The requested operation is invalid

But only when I use the PowerApps form. I have the exact same fields in both the SP Default form, and the PowerApps form.
If I use SP default form, it submits with no problem, but if I use PowerApps - I get the error. I have no idea what this means or how to resolve it. There are two required fields (both visible on both forms).
Thanks.
